# Wordpress template without blog pages

Tags: wordpress

I chose Wordpress for my last project but I have a question. I'll use **Pages** so the client is able to change the content himself. For the moment there are no **Post** or blog in it. Is it possible to run Wordpess without a blog? It'll be a blog in a future but not now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely you can have a WordPress site without a blog. You just need to do a couple of things in the admin.

First you need to create 2 pages: a static 'home' page, and a 'blog index' page. The home page is what will be displayed when a visitor comes to the site. The blog index page is just a blank page, with a title you can remember.

Next, in Settings > Reading, select Front page displays a 'static page', then set 'Front page:' to the home page you made, and 'Posts page:' to the blog index page you made.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for sure you can do this.

Just do the following:

- In your admin backend click on **Settings** -> **Reading** and set "A Static Page"
- Go to **Appearance** and build a **custom menu** and add there your pages to a active menu.
- **Disable** all widgets which link to posts.

In fact you need only the first step, but with the second you allow users to navigate on your site. To make the UX better, just add a plugin like [Map Categories to Pages](http://wordpress.org/plugins/map-categories-to-pages/) to add a category widget or something in this way, to let people browse your site more nicely.